# Task with number of tiles

Tags: algorithms

I have a tile □ with 1x1(n=1) dimensions. I can have 2x1(n=2) tile □□, etc.
I have to find out in how many ways can i arrange them(for inputed n).
For example:
n=3
combinations: □□□,□□ □,□ □□,□ □ □
I hope you can help me.

Comment: sorry if my english is bad

Comment: Why did you tag 3 different languages?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Do they always have to be in a single row?  If so, then it's just 2**(n-1), i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8, etc. (there are n-1 borders, and each border may or may not have a gap).

Comment: This really isn't a programming question, but rather a math question.   @TomKarzes's solution looks correct.

Comment: @Tom Karzes the fact that some of the things can be made with a 2x1 tile changes things up a bit. Unless I'm misinterpreting the question...

Answer (score 1):

As a hint:

- There's one way to express a 0 x n row (namely, don't put any tiles down).
- There's one way to express a 1 x n row (namely, a 1 x 1 tile).
- If you have an (n + 2) x 1 row, you can either put a 1 x 1 tile as the leftmost tile (and then tile the remaining (n + 1) x 1 row) or a 2 x 1 tile as the leftmost tile (and then tile the remaining (n x 1) row).

Write a recurrence based on this. Seem familiar? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need ordered partitions of $n$, these are called compositions of $n$ and are well known to be enumerated by $\color{blue}{2^{n-1}}$.